# Return type of operator= - reference or value?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between returning from function "operator="

```
by reference
by value
```

? Both version seems to yield a correct result in the example below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CComplexNumber{
    float m_realPart;
    float m_imagPart;
public:
    CComplexNumber(float r,float i):m_realPart(r),m_imagPart(i){}

    //the following can be also 
    //CComplexNumber& operator=(const CComplexNumber& orig){
    CComplexNumber operator=(const CComplexNumber& orig){
        if (this!=&orig){
            this->m_realPart=orig.m_realPart;
            this->m_imagPart=orig.m_imagPart;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& lhs,CComplexNumber rhs){
        lhs<<"["<<rhs.m_realPart<<","<<rhs.m_imagPart<<"]"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    CComplexNumber a(1,2);
    CComplexNumber b(3,4);
    CComplexNumber c(5,6);

    a=b=c;
    cout<<a<<b<<c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NikBougalis `(a = b) = c` is idomatic C++.  While I can see reasons to block it, I'm not sure they are convincing: you should have strong reasons to make your operators behave unlike operators on primitive types.

Comment: You'll see the difference with `(a=b)=c`. For that to behave like builtin types, you'd need to return a reference.

Comment: @Yakk That should be an answer.

Comment: A reason not to return by value: what is the point of a copy operation performing two copies.

Comment: @Yakk That's a fair point; I didn't actually think of that. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: I do not suggest you return const reference from operator =. Either return reference or make it void.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning by value returns a **copy** of the object. Returning by reference returns the object itself.

Which one you want to use depends on how you want to use the value that was returned. If you want to modify it without affecting the original object (after returning), return by value; otherwise return by reference.

The convention when using the operator= member function is to return by reference. This allows you to chain operations on the object:

```
CComplexNumber a(1,2);
CComplexNumber b(3,4);

(a = b) *= 2; //Assignment of b to a, then scale by 2
```

Now, with return by value after the assignment, the `*=` would not modify the value `a`, since a **copy** of a would be scaled by 2. With return by reference, `b` would be assigned to `a` and `a` itself would be scaled by 2.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a reference (mutable) is the least surprising, and what you really should choose for an operation which is so common it is implicitly declared. Reference is the return type of the default/implicit definitions.

Example:

```
A operator=(const A&) = default; // ERROR
const A& operator=(const A&) = default; // ERROR
A& operator=(const A&) = default; // OK
```

Some compilers will kindly warn you if you do not return a reference in a user defined function.

In addition to the surprising (and sometimes costly) copy, it also avoids slicing.

Returning a const reference could forbid a move.

Comment: What happens if you return void?

Comment: This is not really borrowed from C; the semantics of assignment are different in C and in C++, and in particular, in C, assignment is an rvalue, where as it is an lvalue in C++.

Comment: @JamesKanze removed that bit. ty