# Operator=: return reference vs. value

Tags: c++

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953279/return-type-of-operator-reference-or-value) and am a bit confused. Suppose that I declare a class as:

```
class cls
{
public:
    int x;
    cls(int _x):x(_x){}
    cls& operator=(cls& ob)
    {
        x = ob.x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And then create 2 objects and perform copy operation and then print the addresses of both the variables before and after the assignment operator is overloaded as:

```
cls o1 = 7;
cls o2 = cls(8);
cout<<&o1<<endl;    //0330F880
cout<<&o2<<endl;    //0330F874
o1 = o2;
cout<<&o1<<endl;    //0330F880
cout<<&o2<<endl;    //0330F874
```

Both the address group is same; this is understood as the assignment operator returns by reference.

But I notice that the same address group values are returned if I define my assignment operator to return by value.

In the link referred above, It is answered that a copy of the object will be returned if returned by value. Then why is it returning the same address values. Shouldn't they be different. Please help clear my concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value is only relevant if you do something with it.  For example:

```
(o1 = o2).do_something();
```

Or equivalently:

```
(o1.operator=(o2)).do_something();
```

The `do_something()` method will run on the object returned - in your case the original instance of `o1` since it was returning a reference.  However, if you changed your code to return a value instead, then `do_something()` would be running on a ***copy*** of `o1`.

If you had a third object `cls* o_ptr;` and did the following:

```
cls o1 = 7;
cls o2 = cls(8);
cls* o_ptr = &(o1=o2);
```

If you displayed `o_ptr` you'd see it was the same as `&o1` if you return a reference, but different if you returned a value.

Comment: As the addresses returned before and after call of assignment operator is same, doesn't it mean that is still points to the same object?

Comment: Yes, it still points to the same object.  You still have two objects and they are still allocated in the same spot in memory.  By over-riding the operator, you are effectively doing `o1.operator=(o2)`, which simply copies the value of o2 into o1.  You will still have 2 objects.

Comment: @Saksham: You're not storing pointers to cls objects. You're storing cls objects.  The address of an object never changes through its lifetime.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley do you know any reference where I can get more detail of this? Or if you can elaborate a bit if possible

Comment: @Saksham: [(1)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/value-vs-ref-semantics.html) [(2)](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/)

Comment: @Saksham: When you print the address of an object, you see the address of that object (the place in memory where that object is stored).

Comment: @Saksham: It doesn't matter that you return by reference or by value.  The statement `o1 = o2;` simply copies the data (the `x` member) from `o2` to `o1`. The fact that you're returning a reference only matters if you actually do something with the return value of the whole assignment operation, as explained in Trenin's answer.  You're not doing anything with that value, so it doesn't matter what you return.  You could change it to return nothing (void), and you would still see the same results.

Comment: @Saksham: But just so we're clear, no matter what you do in your code, during a single run of your program, `cout << &o1;` will always print the same value, and `cout << &o2;` will always print the same value (which will always be different from `&o1`). Because during a single run of a program, an object's address never ever changes.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley got your point. Thanks again. Didn't read the answer properly which led to me getting confused.

Answer (score -1):

I think, that address is the same, because you are only overwriting inner content of structure, not its place in memory.